# What does$ [0,1]\times [0,1)$ represent in $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

What does$ [0,1]\times [0,1)$ represent in $\mathbb R^2$?

I don't quite understand this format as a set.
What points does it contain?

Comment: Almost all of the standard $1\times 1$ square, top edge missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$[0,1]\times[0,1) =\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x\in [0,1], y\in [0,1)\}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y<1\}.$$